# Why Do I get Can't locate Module/Find.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, cpan

Ok so I've been trying to get this source up to work for my game but after I install all of the modules I receive this error in my terminal.

```
PS C:\Users\NAME\desktop\Luna> perl Run.pm
Can't locate Module/Find.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at Run.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Run.pm line 8.
```

I don't understand why i'm getting it

and here is line 8

```
use Module::Find;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a Module::Find installed?

Comment: Yes but I just figured out that it's trying to get the modules from the perl64/lib/ folder but the files aren't there. So I looked in C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib and they're in that folder. Do you have any idea how I can make it use that folder instead of the perl64?

Comment: Sounds like you have two installations of Perl (one in `C:\Perl64`, and one in `C:\strawberry\perl`). One has the module installed, and the other doesn't. Install it for the build you are using, or use the build that has it installed.

Comment: so how do I use the strawberry one?

Comment: Use `c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl,exe` instead of `c:\perl64\bin\perl.exe` to execute your program. (Guessing at the exact paths)

Comment: It seems like it worked when I deleted the perl64 folder

Comment: You probably have both in your `PATH`, with `c:\perl64\bin` appearing first.

Comment: Yea but I deleted those and that file so the issue is fixed.

Comment: Technically, you just had to fix your `PATH` (which is still wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This points out why it is important to understand a bit about using the computer one chooses to use. In this case, you have two Perl installations. In one, `perl.exe` lives in `c:\perl64\bin` (I am assuming that is [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl)). The other `perl.exe` lives in `c:\strawberry\perl\bin`. It seems you managed to install (possibly via a `cpanm` that only appears in `c:\strawberry\perl\bin`) `Module::Find` for [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Apparently, in your environment, `c:\perl64\bin` comes before `c:\strawberry\perl\bin`. Therefore, your `perl Run.pm`, you invoke the `perl` in that directory. Each installation has a number of default places where it looks for modules (you can list those using `perl -V). ActiveState's`perl.exe` will not be looking for modules in Strawberry Perl's directories.

It is possible to have multiple Perl installations co-exist peacefully in Windows, but it becomes more complicated than necessary due to the [shortcomings](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/06/msg228353.html) of [tools](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.24.0/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl) that generate batch files that invoke installed Perl scripts. These tools just invoke `perl` as opposed to putting the full path to the `perl.exe` that was used to create the batch file.

Until that becomes the default, the easiest way I have found of dealing with this situation is designating one Perl distro as my default, and using a number of batch file and symbolic link tricks to switch between that and others.

Comment: I know how to use a computer but I just didn't realized that I had two versions of perl installed but thank you tho.

Answer (score -1):

Go to CPAN command prompt (for perl C:\Strawberry\perl\bin)

cpan> install

or any  for example

install Locale::Language

Comment: Please use proper text formatting and be specific.